# Me llega la información al controlador de mi array vacía

Tags: ajax, json

Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema, tengo un array con los siguientes valores:

```
 0: {Periodo: "2021", Departamento: "CLS", Regla: "GE3", Descripcion: "Gestion", Puntos: "12",...}
 1: {Periodo: "2021", Departamento: "DEC", Regla: "GE3", Descripcion: "Gestion", Puntos: "12",...}
```

En donde hago el llamado del AJAX de la siguiente manera:

```
    flagToPreventDoubles = true;
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("RegistraNuevoPeriodoForm")',
            data: { data: auxObj },
      success: fuction(data) {
         alert("Se genero su registro");
      },
      error: function() {
            alert('Ocurrio un error');
            flagToPreventDoubles = false;
      }
   });
}
```

**ERROR:**

El error en si es que al momento de recibirlo en el controlador este no me llega nada, me llega nulo.

El siguiente es el controlador en el que espero que me llegue la información

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RegistraNuevoPeriodoForm(string[] data)
{

       return Json("NOT OK"); 
   }
}
```

**Actualización:**

Siguiendo la recomendación de la respuesta de crear un nuevo objeto con estructura idéntica lo que tengo ahora es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en el response del network de tu navegador que te dice?

Comment: @DonaldoManzano Te refieres a la consola del navegador ?

Comment: Tienes un objeto que contiene `data.auxObj ` o solamente es `auxObj `, de ser asi solo pon `data: auxObj`

Comment: @JuanRivera Te refieres a colocar en la linea `data: { auxObj },`

Comment: No es necesario las llaves, solo envia el dato `data: auxObj `

Comment: @JuanRivera Sigue igual, no me devuelve nada el controlador, por si acaso sirve algo el `auxObj` lo inicializo así `let auxObj = [];`

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que pasas como:

```
0: {Periodo: "2021", Departamento: "CLS", Regla: "GE3", Descripcion: "Gestion", Puntos: "12",...}
1: {Periodo: "2021", Departamento: "DEC", Regla: "GE3", Descripcion: "Gestion", Puntos: "12",...}
```

Es (digamos representado en javascript) lo siguiente:

```
var miarreglo = [
   {Periodo: "2021", Departamento: "CLS", Regla: "GE3", Descripcion: "Gestion", Puntos: "12",...},
   {Periodo: "2021", Departamento: "DEC", Regla: "GE3", Descripcion: "Gestion", Puntos: "12",...}
];
```

Realmente lo que estas enviando es un arreglo de objeto; y tu controlador:

```
public JsonResult RegistraNuevoPeriodoForm(string[] data)
```

Lo que recibe es un arreglo de string; por tanto lo que te sugiero pruebes es lo siguiente:

1. Crear un objeto con estructura idéntica a la que recibe; por ejemplo:

```
class MiObjeto {
   public string Periodo { get; set; }
   /* y las demas declararlas también */
}
```

Entonces tu controlador quedaria:

```
public JsonResult RegistraNuevoPeriodoForm(MiObjeto[] data)
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

[Pasar una lista de objetos con Ajax a Controlador en MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242414/passing-a-list-of-objects-into-an-mvc-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax) cambia `data: { data: auxObj },` por `data: JSON.stringify({ data: auxObj }),`

> Por si al caso; en la clase que indico se me paso que debe estar como `public` asì como c/u de  las propiedades de la misma.

En teoría es similar pero igual prueba con:

```
public JsonResult RegistraNuevoPeriodoForm(MiObjeto[] data)
```

y

```
public JsonResult RegistraNuevoPeriodoForm(List<MiObjeto> data)
```

> Desde luego sin haber quitado el `[HttpPost]` que de inicio le tienes puesto.

Comment: Te refieres a realizar una nueva clase así como la que tengo en mi ultima actualización de pregunta ?

Comment: De igual modo lo probé con el nuevo objeto que cree y me sigue devolviendo null

Comment: Saludos. @JohnDoe actualice; solo mira que `auxObj` no sea nulo; que tenga dato(s) que estas enviando; con un `console.log(auxObj);` puedes verificar el valor; colocando este justo antes del llamado al **Ajax**.

Comment: El objeto sería `public JsonResult RegistraNuevoPeriodoForm(List<MiObjeto> data)` el de la imagen que agregue en mi ultima actualización ?

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Sí, en efecto @JohnDoe .